# Setting date format on datepicker.js from datepicker localization file

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

Localizing jquery ui datepicker with an i18n localization file is pretty straightforward but setting the datepicker's `dateFormat` property to the default property found in hte i18n file is proving challenging. In the following file for France you can see the default date format specifying day,month,year

```
(function( factory ) {
if ( typeof define === "function" && define.amd ) {

    // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
    define([ "../datepicker" ], factory );
} else {

    // Browser globals
    factory( jQuery.datepicker );
}
}(function( datepicker ) {

datepicker.regional['fr'] = {
closeText: 'Fermer',
prevText: 'Précédent',
nextText: 'Suivant',
currentText: 'Aujourd\'hui',
monthNames: ['janvier', 'février', 'mars', 'avril', 'mai', 'juin',
    'juillet', 'août', 'septembre', 'octobre', 'novembre', 'décembre'],
monthNamesShort: ['janv.', 'févr.', 'mars', 'avr.', 'mai', 'juin',
    'juil.', 'août', 'sept.', 'oct.', 'nov.', 'déc.'],
dayNames: ['dimanche', 'lundi', 'mardi', 'mercredi', 'jeudi', 'vendredi', 'samedi'],
dayNamesShort: ['dim.', 'lun.', 'mar.', 'mer.', 'jeu.', 'ven.', 'sam.'],
dayNamesMin: ['D','L','M','M','J','V','S'],
weekHeader: 'Sem.',
dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
firstDay: 1,
isRTL: false,
showMonthAfterYear: false,
yearSuffix: ''};
datepicker.setDefaults(datepicker.regional['fr']);

return datepicker.regional['fr'];

}));
```

This is how I am setting the localization file dynamically at runtime.

```
 if (General.CountryCode != "US") {
            var scriptUrl = "/Scripts/datepicker-glob/datepicker-" + General.CountryCode.toLowerCase() + ".js";

            console.log("fetching script: ", scriptUrl);
            //now get datepicker local file and load it into the dom
            $.getScript(scriptUrl).fail(function() {
                console.log("script fetch failed");
            });
            console.log("loaded script. Setting defaults for datepicker");
            //console.log("dateformat: ", $.datepicker.regional[General.CountryCode.toLowerCase()].dateFormat);
            //now set the default on all datepickers
            console.log($.datepicker);
            //console.log($.datepicker);
            $.datepicker.setDefaults(
               $.extend(
                  {
                      'dateFormat': $.datepicker.regional[0].dateFormat
                  },
                 $.datepicker.regional[General.CountryCode.toLowerCase()]
                )
              );
            console.log("defaults set.");
        }
```

The following line `'dateFormat': $.datepicker.regional[0].dateFormat` in the `$.extend` fails because `$.datepicker.regional[0]` seems to be undefined; however, the following line `console.log($.datepicker);` returns the following:

[image]

According to that shot it looks as if my code should be working.

**How can I correctly retrieve the regional dateFormat value from a dynamically loaded i18n file?**

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to retrieve the default date values. This is not technically an answer to my question but I will provide my solution in case it will help others. I ended up creating a dictionary of country code to dateformat.

```
 RegionDateFormatDict: [
{
    key: "af", value: "d/m/yy"
},
{
    key: "ar", value: "d/m/yy"
},
{
    key: "az", value: "d.m.yy"
},
{
    key: "be", value: "d.m.yy"
},
{
    key: "bg", value: "d.m.yy"
},
{
    key: "bs", value: "d.m.yy"
},
{
    key: "ca", value: "d/m/yy"
},
{
    key: "cs", value: "d.m.yy"
},
{
    key: "cy-gb", value: "d/m/yy"
},
{
    key: "cy", value: "d/m/yy"  
},
{
    key: "da", value: "d-m-yy"
},
{
    key: "de", value: "d.m.yy"
},
{
    key: "el", value: "d/m/yy"
},
{
    key: "en-au", value: "d/m/yy"
},
{
    key: "en-gb", value: "d/m/yy"
},
{
    key: "en-nz", value: "d/m/yy"
},
{
    key: "en", value: "d/m/yy"  
},
{
    key: "eo", value: "d/m/yy"
},
{
    key: "es", value: "d/m/yy"
},
{
    key: "et", value: "d.m.yy"
},
{
    key: "eu", value: "yy-m-d"
},
{
    key: "fa", value: "yy/m/d"
},
{
    key: "fi", value: "d.m.yy"
},
{
    key: "fo", value: "d-m-yy"
},
{
    key: "fr-ca", value: "yy-m-d"
},
{
    key: "fr-ch", value: "d.m.yy"
},
{
    key: "fr", value: "d/m/yy"
},
{
    key: "gl", value: "d/m/yy"
},
{
    key: "he", value: "d/m/yy"
},
{
    key: "hi", value: "d/m/yy"
},
{
    key: "hr", value: "d.m.yy."
},
{
    key: "hu", value: "yy.m.d."
},
{
    key: "hy", value: "d.m.yy"
},
{
    key: "id", value: "d/m/yy"
},
{
    key: "is", value: "d.m.yy"
},
{
    key: "it-ch", value: "d.m.yy"
},
{
    key: "it", value: "d/m/yy"
},
{
    key: "ja", value: "yy/m/d"
},
{
    key: "ka", value: "d-m-yy"
},
{
    key: "kk", value: "d.m.yy"
},
{
    key: "km", value: "d-m-yy"
},
{
    key: "ko", value: "yy-m-d"
},
{
    key: "ky", value: "d.m.yy"
},
{
    key: "lb", value: "d.m.yy"
},
{
    key: "lt", value: "yy-m-d"
},
{
    key: "lv", value: "d.m.yy"
},
{
    key: "mk", value: "d.m.yy"
},
{
    key: "ml", value: "d/m/yy"
},
{
    key: "ms", value: "d/m/yy"
},
{
    key: "nb", value: "d.m.yy"
},
{
    key: "nl-be", value: "d/m/yy"
},
{
    key: "nl", value: "d-m-yy"
},
{
    key: "nn", value: "d.m.yy"
},
{
    key: "no", value: "d.m.yy"
},
{
    key: "pl", value: "d.m.yy"
},
{
    key: "pt-br", value: "d/m/yy"
},
{
    key: "pt", value: "d/m/yy"
},
{
    key: "rm", value: "d/m/yy"
},
{
    key: "ro", value: "d.m.yy"
},
{
    key: "ru", value: "d.m.yy"
},
{
    key: "sk", value: "d.m.yy"
},
{
    key: "sl", value: "d.m.yy"
},
{
    key: "sq", value: "d.m.yy"
},
{
    key: "sr-sr", value: "d.m.yy"
},
{
    key: "sr", value: "d.m.yy"
},
{
    key: "sv", value: "yy-m-d"
},
{
    key: "ta", value: "d/m/yy"
},
{
    key: "th", value: "d/m/yy"
},
{
    key: "tj", value: "d.m.yy"
},
{
    key: "tr", value: "d.m.yy"
},
{
    key: "uk", value: "d.m.yy"
},
{
    key: "vi", value: "d/m/yy"
},
{
    key: "zh-cn", value: "yy-m-d"
},
{
    key: "zh-hk", value: "d-m-yy"
},
{
    key: "zh-tw", value: "yy/m/d"
},
{
    key: "zh", value: "yy/m/d"
}]
```

All leading 0's on day and month have been taken off from each format.